Interchangeability of 犯す and 冒す

...三人の考えがスネイプの耳の入るような危険を犯すわけにはいかない。
They couldn't afford to run the risk of their thoughts reaching Snape's ears.

I'm familiar with 犯す meaning 'to commit', 'to violate' etc. These are the only meanings given by Jisho, Weblio and my paper bilingual dictionary.
When I look for おかす in my paper monolingual dictionary I find 危険を冒す as the first entry under 冒す. It again does not have this 'to take a risk' meaning under 犯す.
冒す is a new word for me. I'm wondering to what extent it is interchangeable with 犯す. The dictionaries seem to suggest that it isn't. But from the passage above and a quick check on google I see that 危険を犯す is used. Is this fine or is it just a common abuse?

I would say it's a common abuse.

Practically, you can think 犯す and 冒す are uninterchangeable.
It is more or less a matter of collocation. 危険をおかす is always 冒す and 危険を犯す is an error.
In terms of meaning, 犯す is for wrong doing (犯罪=crime, or violation) and 冒す is for daringly doing something (as used in 冒険=adventure). But there can be vague cases, so you should just remember 危険を冒す.

There is also another 侵す, meaning invading territory.

「冒す」「犯す」「侵す」　「おかす」の使い分け
風邪や病気に「おかされる」というときの漢字は？

